# Trim audio file using start and stop times

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, trim

I have an FFmpeg command to trim audio:

```
ffmpeg -ss 01:43:46 -t 00:00:44.30 -i input.mp3 output.mp3
```

The problem I have with this command is that option `-t` requires a duration (in seconds) from *01:43:46*. I want to trim audio using start/stop times, e.g. between *01:43:46* and *00:01:45.02*.

Is this possible?

Comment: So you want to extract a section of an audio file using start and stop times instead of a start time and a duration, is that correct?

Comment: @Nasha That's correct. I'll edit the post to make that clearer.

Comment: I have rephrased your question accordingly. Indeed `ffmpeg` doesn't seem to provide anything else than a start time and a duration. And `mplayer` doesn't either.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

ffmpeg seems to have a new option **-to** in [the documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Main-options):

> **-to** *position* (*input*/*output*)
>   Stop writing the output or reading the input at *position*. *position*
>   must be a time duration specification, see [(ffmpeg-utils)the Time
>   duration section in the ffmpeg-utils(1) manual.](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#time-duration-syntax)
>
> -to and -t are mutually exclusive and -t has priority.

Sample command with two time formats

```
ffmpeg -i file.mkv -ss 20 -to 40 -c copy file-2.mkv
ffmpeg -i file.mkv -ss 00:00:20 -to 00:00:40 -c copy file-2.mkv
```

This should create a copy (file-2.mkv) of file.mkv from the 20 second mark to the 40 second mark.

Comment: Tx, that works nicely. I find that if I don't remove the `copy` part the audio/video is out of sync, so I remove that and add `-async 1` and it works like a charm. Of course it requires reencoding, so an improvement would be a command that would allow for the `copy` but without the sync issues.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple intervals and they would be joined together? i.e. `ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -ss 10 -to 11 -ss 20 -to 21 -ss 30 -to 31 ....`

Comment: @AvnerBarr I don't know if this is possible solely with FFmpeg, but I know it's possible with Mencoder. This works, using the `-to` option : `ffmpeg -i mmm.mp4 -ss 00:04:04 -to 00:04:35 -c copy output1.mp4 && ffmpeg -i mmm.mp4 -ss 00:05:47 -to 00:06:05 -c copy output2.mp4 && mencoder -ovc copy -oac mp3lame -idx output1.mp4 output2.mp4 -o complete.mp4`

Answer (score -1):

If you have PHP installed, make it a script:

TimeDiff.php contents:

```
<?php
// Create datetime objcects
$dt1 = new DateTime($argv[1]);
$dt2 = new DateTime($argv[2]);

// Conver difference to seconds
$dt3 = $dt2->format('U') - $dt1->format('U');

// echo $dt3."\n";
$h = (int)($dt3 / 3600);
$dt3 %= 3600;
$m = (int)($dt3 / 60);
$dt3 %= 60;
$s = $dt3;

// Dump as H:M:S
echo $h . ":" . $m . ":" . $s;

?>
```

audiochop.sh contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
INFILE=$1
START=$2
STOP=$3
OUTFILE=$4

OFFSET=`php TimeDiff.php "$START" "$STOP"`

echo "Disecting $INFILE starting from $START to $STOP (duration $OFFSET)"
ffmpeg -ss "$START" -t "$OFFSET" -i "$INFILE" "$OUTFILE"
```

Usage:

```
./audiochop.sh [input.mp3] [startchop] [stopchop] [output.mp3]
```

Where [startchop] and [stopchop] are both absolute timestamps from the beginning of the track.

NB: Script(s) may need tweaking depending on platform version etc...

Comment: So does the command look like the following example? audiochop.sh input.mp3 00:01:30 00:01:50 output.mp3

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: This is actually the full command: ./audiochop.sh input.mp3 00:01:30 00:01:50 output.mp3 I had forgotten to put the period and slash in front of the command, which is why it wasn't working.

Comment: Incidentally, I found that this php/bash script also works on mp4 videos, so I assume it will work with any video format.

Comment: It should work with whatever format your ffmpeg supports.