# Adjust content of yad script for kdialog or other better KDE solution (python etc)

Tags: shell-script, kde, ffmpeg, multimedia, kdialog

I use this script to cut media files at selected time:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=$(yad --width=600 --height=400 --file-selection --file-filter='*.m4a *.ogg *.mp3 *.mp4 *.avi *.aac *.flac *.avi *.mkv *.mp4')

eval $(yad --width=400 --form --field=start --field=end --field=output:SFL "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "${INPUT/%.*}-out.${INPUT##*.}" | awk -F'|' '{printf "START=%s\nEND=%s\nOUTPUT=\"%s\"\n", $1, $2, $3}')
[[ -z $START || -z $END || -z $OUTPUT ]] && exit 1

DIFF=$(($(date +%s --date="$END")-$(date +%s --date="$START")))
OFFSET=""$(($DIFF / 3600)):$(($DIFF / 60 % 60)):$(($DIFF % 60))

ffmpeg -ss "$START" -t "$OFFSET" -i "$INPUT" -c copy "$OUTPUT"
```

I have found it [HERE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186595/341192) initially and only changed the last line (to cut/copy without conversion).

But I am in KDE and would like to use `kdialog` for a better interaction.

The first part, starting with  `INPUT=$(yad` can be adjusted like so, I guess:

`INPUT=$(kdialog --getopenfilename ~/Videos/ '*.m4a *.ogg *.mp3 *.mp4 *.avi *.aac *.flac *.avi *.mkv *.mp4')`

But then I don't find an alternative in `kdialog` to the second part (starting with `eval $(yad --width=400 --form --field=start --field=end --field=output:SFL "00:00:00" "00:00:00" ...`) so that it shows a window where the timestamp start and end could be entered:

[image]

---

(In case this is possible I would also like to have a progress bar or message and a "ok" message at the end. -
Please feel free to suggest other solutions than kdialog if available for KDE.)

Comment: serious question, if you're on KDE and want good KDE integration, why do a shell script? PyQt5 is pretty usable, and the thing you're trying to write would be a relatively short Python script, without dependeny on yad.

Comment: I'm going to roll back your replacement of the source code with the image. I can read your source code just fine, some of us can't read pictures (e.g. because they have bad vision and that thing just won't scale), and atop of that, I can't copy and paste text from an image

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my question was explicit enough, but the whole problem was in this sentence:

> I am in KDE and would like to use kdialog for a better interaction.

But the only thing that was "no good" KDE-interaction-wise was the GTK UI of the file picker and of the timestamp window. The former was more important than the latter: the file picker was also stuck at $HOME level and I was not able to find a `yad --file` option to specify another location in the way `kdialog --getopenfilename` has.

My solution here only goes as far: using `kdialog` for the file picker and leaving `yad` for the timestamp window (which I don't know how to create with `kdialog`); I wasn't able to make a progress bar with `kdialog`, so I have found a way to make one with `zenity` (not really showing the percentual progress, just the fact that action is underway); end-message was easy to create with `kdialog`.

```
#!/bin/bash


INPUT=$(kdialog --getopenfilename ~/Videos/ '*.m4a *.ogg *.mp3 *.mp4 *.avi *.aac *.flac *.avi *.mkv *.mp4')

eval $(yad --width=400 --form --field=start --field=end --field=output:SFL "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "${INPUT/%.*}-out.${INPUT##*.}" | awk -F'|' '{printf "START=%s\nEND=%s\nOUTPUT=\"%s\"\n", $1, $2, $3}')
[[ -z $START || -z $END || -z $OUTPUT ]] && exit 1

DIFF=$(($(date +%s --date="$END")-$(date +%s --date="$START")))
OFFSET=""$(($DIFF / 3600)):$(($DIFF / 60 % 60)):$(($DIFF % 60))

ffmpeg -ss "$START" -t "$OFFSET" -i "$INPUT" -c copy "$OUTPUT" | zenity --progress --pulsate --text="Running" --percentage=1 --auto-close --auto-kill

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
kdialog --msgbox "Process completed successfully!"
  else
kdialog --msgbox "SOMETHING WENT WRONG!"
fi
```

(I realize this way of mixing `kdialog`, `zenity` and `yad` is odd, and i am waiting for a cleaner solution, preferably with just `kdialog`, but I don't know how to make a progressbar and a timestamp window with that.)