# Split audio into several pieces based on timestamps from a text file with sox or ffmpeg

Tags: ubuntu, audio, ffmpeg, sox

I looked at the following link: [Trim audio file using start and stop times](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182602/trim-audio-file-using-start-and-stop-times?newreg=ff8310e737744266bfecb9b2003b2af3)

But this doesn't completely answer my question. My problem is: I have an audio file such as `abc.mp3` or `abc.wav`. I also have a text file containing start and end timestamps:

```
0.0 1.0 silence  
1.0 5.0 music  
6.0 8.0 speech
```

I want to split the audio into three parts using Python and `sox`/`ffmpeg`, thus resulting in three seperate audio files.

How do I achieve this using either `sox` or `ffmpeg`?

Later I want to compute the [MFCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum) corresponding to those portions using `librosa`.

I have `Python 2.7`, `ffmpeg`, and `sox` on an Ubuntu Linux 16.04 installation.

Comment: As that question says, it seems to be a case of finding the durations for the snippets from the timestamps - have you looked at https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects and then to use ffmpeg, either https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=Ffmpeg&submit=search or the subprocess module https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess I reckon.

Comment: No problem. I'll try and add a proper answer tomorrow if no one else has, once I've got on my main computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just had a quick go at it, very little in the way of testing so maybe it'll be of help. Below relies on [ffmpeg-python](https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/), but it wouldn't be a challenge to write with `subprocess` anyway.

At the moment the time input file is just treated as pairs of times, start and end, and then an output name. Missing names are replaced as `linecount.wav`

```
import ffmpeg
from sys import argv

""" split_wav `audio file` `time listing`

    `audio file` is any file known by local FFmpeg
    `time listing` is a file containing multiple lines of format:
        `start time` `end time` output name 

    times can be either MM:SS or S*
"""

_in_file = argv[1]

def make_time(elem):
    # allow user to enter times on CLI
    t = elem.split(':')
    try:
        # will fail if no ':' in time, otherwise add together for total seconds
        return int(t[0]) * 60 + float(t[1])
    except IndexError:
        return float(t[0])

def collect_from_file():
    """user can save times in a file, with start and end time on a line"""

    time_pairs = []
    with open(argv[2]) as in_times:
        for l, line in enumerate(in_times):
            tp = line.split()
            tp[0] = make_time(tp[0])
            tp[1] = make_time(tp[1]) - tp[0]
            # if no name given, append line count
            if len(tp) < 3:
                tp.append(str(l) + '.wav')
            time_pairs.append(tp)
    return time_pairs

def main():
    for i, tp in enumerate(collect_from_file()):
        # open a file, from `ss`, for duration `t`
        stream = ffmpeg.input(_in_file, ss=tp[0], t=tp[1])
        # output to named file
        stream = ffmpeg.output(stream, tp[2])
        # this was to make trial and error easier
        stream = ffmpeg.overwrite_output(stream)

        # and actually run
        ffmpeg.run(stream)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: my upvote will appear once I reach 15 points, sorry about that new member difficulties!